# Issue with Copying Files between Timestamp in UNIX

Tags: date, unix, timestamp

My Requirement is to pull all the files generated between 2 timestamps (user Input for the time stamp should be in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:24MI:SS". I am using START and END variables for another query hence i cannot change the format )

```
echo "Enter Start Time ( Format :- DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS )"
read START
start=$(echo $START|sed 's/-//g'|sed 's/://g'|sed 's/ //g'|sed 's ..$  ')
echo "Enter End Time  (Format :- DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS )"
read END
end=$(echo $END|sed 's/-//g'|sed 's/://g'|sed 's/ //g'|sed 's ..$  ')
touch -t $start old.txt
touch -t $end new.txt
find <SOURCE> -name "*.sarm" -type f -cnewer old.txt ! -newernew.txt -exec cp -p "{}" <TARGET>\;
```

Issue : I want to pull the files 10mins before START time and after END time.This should be transparent to the user.

Example : 
User will enter as below
             ``START = '2014-05-06 00:00:00'
END   = '2014-05-06 02:00:00'`

Files with the modified date  between  `'2014-05-05 23:50:00'  and '2014-05-06 02:10:00'` are copied.I am stuck with this. Please assist.

Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use date to do time calculations, also you don't need all those sed commands to achieve what you want:

```
root@lopobox:~# date -d "2014-05-06 00:00:00+000 -10 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20140505235000
root@lopobox:~# date -d "2014-05-06 00:00:00+000 +10 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20140506001000
```

PS. Mind you that you may need to adjust you time zone in this case I use UTC `+000`. If I wanted to adjust to BST I would use `+100`

I hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Removed the "%S" formatting to create time stamp.             earlier=$(date -d "$START+1000 -10 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M)
touch -t $earlier old.txt